# Numbering depends on changing cell values in another column - vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I want give the initial number in the macro (in this example T00101) and I want to fill the empty cells in column A with codes if it meets the condition (in Column C it has "good" value), so that it would be increased by 1 if there is no change in the cells in column B and by 100 (counted from the first appearance of the previous name) if there is a change in column B.

The cells in A would remain empty if in column C the word is "false". 
That is the first appearance of the word always ends with 01, the second appearance of the word ends with 02. If there is a change in the name, the first 3 digit of the number increases by 1. (the 3 characters after the T letter)

I would like this as a result:

```
A       B        C
Id      Name    Status
T00101  Apple   good
T00102  Apple   good
T00103  Apple   good
T00201  Peach   good
T00301  Orange  good
        Banana  false
T00401  Grapes  good
T00402  Grapes  good
```

I have this, but it doesn't work properly... any other suggestions for the macro?

```
Sub numbering()
    Sheet1.Select
    Dim Start As Long
    Dim Piece As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Start = 00101
    Piece = 0
    For i = erow To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 3) = "good" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Start
            If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
                Piece = Piece + 1
                Start = Start + 1
            Else:
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Start - Piece + 100
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When posting code please use indentation to make it readable.

Comment: `it doesn't work properly` does not describe the problem in any useful way

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub FillA()
    Dim SeqNum As Long, iNum As Long
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    SeqNum = 100
    iNum = 1
    Range("A2").Value = "T" & Format(SeqNum + iNum, "00000")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To N
        If Cells(i, "C").Value = "good" And Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i - 1, "B").Value Then
            iNum = iNum + 1
            Cells(i, "A").Value = "T" & Format(SeqNum + iNum, "00000")
        End If

        If Cells(i, "C").Value = "good" And Cells(i, "B").Value <> Cells(i - 1, "B").Value Then
            iNum = 1
            SeqNum = SeqNum + 100
            Cells(i, "A").Value = "T" & Format(SeqNum + iNum, "00000")
        End If

        If Cells(i, "C").Value <> "good" Then
            Cells(i, "A") = ""
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Its great and it does that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick and I've added some comments to explain:

```
Sub numbering()
Sheet1.Select
'  You need to treat the Id as a String,
' but also create Integers to keep track of the numbering components
Dim theId As String
Dim idLetter As String
Dim txt_idCategory As String
Dim txt_idNumber As String
Dim idCategory As Integer
Dim idNumber As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

    firstRow = 2 ' sets the first row to start updating the Id
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' finds the last row
    idLetter = "T" ' set your letter
    idNumber = 1 ' first Id number will always be 1

For i = firstRow To lastRow ' loop through the rows
    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "good" Then ' skip the row if Status not equal "good"
        GoTo nextOne
    End If

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then ' if the name changes (or it's the first one)
        idCategory = idCategory + 1 ' increment the category
        idNumber = 1 ' and increment the number
    Else ' otherwise
        idNumber = idNumber + 1 ' just increment the number
    End If

    Select Case Len(CStr(idCategory)) ' based on the length of the category, append "0's" to the front
        Case 1
            txt_idCategory = "00" & CStr(idCategory)
        Case 2
            txt_idCategory = "0" & CStr(idCategory)
        Case 3
            txt_idCategory = CStr(idCategory)
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Category over 3 digits not catered for, macro will end"
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    Select Case Len(CStr(idNumber)) ' based on the length of the number, append "0's" to the front
        Case 1
            txt_idNumber = "0" & CStr(idNumber)
        Case 2
            txt_idNumber = CStr(idNumber)
            MsgBox "Id Number over 2 digits not catered for, macro will end"
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    theId = idLetter & txt_idCategory & txt_idNumber ' put all 3 parts together
    Cells(i, 1).Value = theId ' update the cell with the id

nextOne:
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like Gary's Student answered as I was creating my code in Excel. I like Gary's answer as it's more condensed, however if it's possible that you will more than 999 different Name (eg Apple, Peach) or more than 99 Names the same (eg Apple appears on 100+ rows), you will need to allow for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and i'm really thankful for the explanations too.

Comment: @Hunga Pleasure